# Minicart doesn't update after successful PayPal payment, magento2

Tags: magento2, paypal

When a customer does an payment trough PayPal the minicart in Mage2 doesn't get cleared. However, the cart itself is absolutely empty.

Is there any way to reset the mini cart on the `success.phtml`, or deleting the whole cart in the `success.phtml` ? 
Thanks

Comment: I also facing it, As I see Its some cache/Static files issue I think

Comment: Its a known bug at Magento2. Check out their Github to stay informed!